# Can't ping server unless server initiates ping to client

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns, ping

Im having a weird issue.

Like the title reads, I can't ping the server unless I first ping a client from the server. Only then am I able to ping the server from the client. While unable to ping the server, it can still browse the web and access network drives.

- tcp/ip settings are correct
- Firewall isn't the issue
- No duplicate IP's on network
- Server isn't under heavy load

This server is a vm, sharing a host with 3 other vm servers. The remaining 3 servers are fine. This particular VM is using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: This IS a firewall issue.  There is some kind of firewall with connection tracking going on somewhere.  Unfortunately I do Linux, not Windows, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: Turn off whatever firewall/security software is in place on both the server and client, then report back on what, if anything, this changes. Also, please 1) more clearly indicate what type of VM/computer the "client" is in this question, and 2) from what device you can "still browse the web..." (client?)